# Trigonometry Identity Help

Tags: trigonometry

How can you proof
$$\tan x / (\tan 2x - \tan x) = \cos 2x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tan 2x -\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos 2x\cos x} = \frac{\tan x}{\cos 2x}.$$

Comment: This is my way.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\tan(x)$ can be written as:

$$\tan (2x-x) = \dfrac{\tan (2x) - \tan(x)}{1+\tan(2x)\tan(x)}$$

So your left hand expression can be rewritten as:

$$\dfrac{1}{1+\tan (2x) \tan (x)}  = \dfrac{1-\tan^2 (x)}{1+\tan^2 (x)}$$

which is nothing but $\cos(2x)$

Answer (score 1):

we use that $$\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}$$ and we get
$$\frac{\tan(x)(1-\tan^2(x))}{2\tan(x)-\tan(x)+\tan^3(x)}=\frac{1-\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos(2x)$$